# Ceiling light with 2 switches

Tags: ceiling

I took a old ceiling light out and when I unscrewed it it fell,I have 2 switches and a red wire,where does the red wire go to

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Would you take a picture of the wires hanging out of the lamp box, and tell us what switches control the ceiling light?

Comment: There are 2 switches in the hallway the light has 3 white and black coming from all sides of the box the one with the red one only has black red and ground the white was cut way back,sorry I can't get a picture

Comment: Just 2 up down switches

Comment: Should I try just connecting the red to the black wire from the light